# How can i add different database name i.e one for development and other for production in mongodb atlas

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

[image]

I want to add two different database for my node app in mongodb atlas in same cluster i.e. one for production and one for development but mongodb atlas is not showing databasename or myfirstfile after @cluster0.irbg7.mongodb.net/ in the below url. How do i add different database in such situations?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you already created the cluster. In one cluster you can add multiple Databases.

On your home page, you are able to see something like this.
[image]
Click on the `Browse Collections` to browse the collections.

[image]

Now `create Database` as much as you like.

- To connect to the desired database, use the connection string followed by database name.

Example: `'mongodb://<username>:<password>@<clustername>/<dbname>?ssl=true&replicaSet=<replica setname>&authSource=admin`

Comment: I did the above process but during connection eg. 'mongodb://<username>:<password>@<clustername>?ssl=true&replicaSet=<replica setname>&authSource=admin          my <dbname> is not showing in the link and if i try to connect to db without <dbname> its getting connected but with <dbname> its showing error.